# Copy constructor not working?

Tags: c++, oop, copy-constructor

Somewhat new to OOP (i.e. C programmer converting to C++) and cannot figure out why my data members in my backpack class are empty.  I make pass an array of potions to my backpack, yet the data members are saying mType = "" (i.e. nothing).

I have never felt this lost in a program before.  Starting to hate OOP (i.e. kidding...but this extremely frustrating).

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rogue.h"
#include "weapon.h"
#include "backpack.h"
#include "potion.h"
#include "coinpouch.h"

int main()
{
Potion myFavoritePotions[5];
myFavoritePotions[0].setName("love");
myFavoritePotions[1].setName("hate");
myFavoritePotions[2].setName("shrink");
myFavoritePotions[3].setName("grow");
myFavoritePotions[4].setName("disappear");
BackPack myFavoriteBackPack(myFavoritePotions);
Weapon myFavoriteWeapon("AK-47");
Weapon mySecretWeapon("Me-262");
Weapon myLeastFavoriteWeapon("Luger");
CoinPouch myFavoritePurse(6,5,4,3);
Rogue myFavoriteRogue("Cynic", myFavoriteWeapon, mySecretWeapon, myFavoriteBackPack, myFavoritePurse);

mySecretWeapon = myFavoriteWeapon;  

myFavoriteRogue.setOffHand(myLeastFavoriteWeapon);
//std::cout << myFavoriteRogue.getOffHand();

return 0;
}
```

**potion.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "potion.h"

//Manager function definitions

//Default constructor
Potion::Potion()
{}

//Constructor
Potion::Potion(std::string name)
:mName(name)
{
std::cout << "Potion's constructor " << std::endl;
}

//Destructor
Potion::~Potion()
{
std::cout << "Potion's destructor " << std::endl;
}

//Copy constructor
Potion::Potion(const Potion & copy)
{
std::cout << "Potion's copy constructor " << std::endl;
}

//Overloaded assignment operator
Potion &Potion::operator= (const Potion & rhs)
{
std::cout << "Potion's overloaded assignment operator. " << std::endl;

return *this;
}

//Setters
void Potion::setName(std::string name)
{
mName = name;
}

//Getters
std::string Potion::getName()
{
return mName;
}
```

**backpack.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "backpack.h"

//Manager function definitions

//Default constructor
BackPack::BackPack()
{}

//Constructor
BackPack::BackPack(Potion Potions[])
{
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    mPotions[i] = Potions[i];
}
std::cout << "Backpack's constructor. " << std::endl;
}

//Destructor
BackPack::~BackPack()
{
std::cout << "Backpack's destructor. " << std::endl;
}

//Copy constructor
BackPack::BackPack(const BackPack & copy)
{
std::cout << "Backpack's copy constructor. " << std::endl;
}

//Overloaded assignment operator
BackPack &BackPack::operator=(const BackPack & rhs)
{
std::cout << "Backpack's assignment operator. " << std::endl;

return *this;
}

//Setters
void BackPack::setPotion(Potion Potions[])
{
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    mPotions[i] = Potions[i];
}
}

//Getters
Potion * BackPack::getPotion()
{
Potion * potionPointer = mPotions;
return potionPointer;
}
```

Comment: try copying the fields from the copy into this.

Answer (score 7):

Your copy constructor doesn't do any copying:

```
//Copy constructor
BackPack::BackPack(const BackPack & copy)
{
std::cout << "Backpack's copy constructor. " << std::endl;
}
```

Neither does your copy assignment operator:

```
//Overloaded assignment operator
BackPack &BackPack::operator=(const BackPack & rhs)
{
std::cout << "Backpack's assignment operator. " << std::endl;

return *this;
}
```

Once you provide your own copy constructor and copy assignment operator, the compiler-generated ones are suppressed. If you need to do some copying, you have to implement it.

(This, of course, applies to *all* your classes.)

Answer (score 5):

If you implement a copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator then you actually have to *implement* the copying. It will not be done for you.

Answer (score 2):

When calling the copy-constructor you must of course assign the values to the to-be-created object...

```
Potion::Potion(const Potion & copy)
{
   //assign the elements from copy to your object here
   std::cout << "Potion's copy constructor " << std::endl;
}
```

The copy-constructor doesn't do this for you.